# Traversing hidden cols in html table

Tags: jquery, html, dom, traversal, html-table

Maybe this question is so easy... I understand html, css, the dom and javascript pretty good, but I'm having a very tough time while trying to get jQuery to work for me. Let's say I have the following 4 columns table, with columns 1 and 3 hidden:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>  
    <tr> 
      <th class="hidden">Column1</th> 
      <th>Column2</th>    
      <th class="hidden">Column3</th> 
      <th>Column4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <td class="hidden">Value1</td> 
      <td>Isle of Palms</td>   
      <td class="hidden">Value3</td>  
      <td>Value4</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I use the following code to hide the hidden class columns:

```
$(function() { 
    $('.hidden').hide();
});
```

Yesterday some of you told me how to get the first column content by using:

```
$(function() { 
    $(this).find('td.hidden:first').html();
});
```

What I want to do is to show an alert or Thickbox showing the header name and cell value for all the hidden columns:

```
Column1 = Value1
Column3 = Value3
```

If it were easier to do, I could group all the hidden columns at the beginning (to the left) of the table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
var mytable = $('#mytable');

$('#mytable > tbody').delegate('tr', 'click', function (e) {

    trToShow = $(this);

    var keyValueInfo = mytable.find('th.hidden').map(function () {

        // for each th.hidden element, get the corresponding "key = value" string

        var i = $(this).index(); // get the index of the th element

        // get the td element with the same index as the above th, and get the text inside it
        var value = trToShow.find('td.hidden').filter(function () {
            return $(this).index() === i;
        }).text();

        // The above could also be done as (Read documentation of :eq selector)
        // var value = trToShow.find('td:eq(' + i + ')').text();

        // get the text inside this th element, which would be our key
        var key = $(this).text();

        // return the "key = value" string wrapped up in a div element
        return '<div>' + key + ' = ' + value + '</div>';

    }).toArray().join('');

});

// Show a dialog with the above content inside it
show_dialog_with_stuff(keyValueInfo);
```

Read more up on [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

<strike>I haven't tested it, but if any, there should only be minor silly errors.</strike> Tested here http://jsfiddle.net/mb6Gd/

Comment: I can even understand your code... so I cannot try it. Where I'm suppose to place the alert with the key + value 'values'? Thanks for your help and sorry about my jquery ignorance.

Comment: I'm glad you asked. Its an awesome way to learn :)
I added some comments, let me know if the code makes sense now. *Edit*: If you need more help, let me know

Comment: Ok, I tried and it returns the hidden headers and hidden columns, but  it's returning values for all the rows in the table. I need to show only the row clicked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know you about that, check the updated version of the code. I assumed there was only one tr :)

Comment: Shrikant

When I try your code, the code for:

 $(function() {
 $('.hidden').hide();
 $('#mytable').css({visibility: "visible"})
 }); doesn't work anymore. Do I need to integrate it with your code? I cannot understand jQuery at all, it seems to complex for me.

Comment: To hide the `.hidden` elements you can do `$('.hidden').hide()`, but I'd recommend hiding them via css, `.hidden { display: none }`. As for the next line of code, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Don't worry, jQuery might seem intimidating at times, but it flows quite naturally, give it some time, and as always, we are here to help you :)

Comment: Ok, I used your CSS #mytable .hidden { display: none } solution now. It's much better. Thanks for the advice. Anyway, your code still not working, it even breaks the javascript onmouseover and onmouseout for hilite and lowlite rows. Thanks anyway, your code looks awesome to me.

Comment: Are those events you talk about are for the `tr` elements? Sorry, but I am not getting the picture here, may be if you post some more code...? I need more context as I can't understand why this won't work.

Comment: Here's a test case of what I understand. http://jsfiddle.net/mb6Gd/ and it seems to work. Let me know what is tripping you off.

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Thank you so much for all your effort and for spending your time solving my problem. You really made my day :)

Comment: @Jorge, well, I am glad it worked out for you. Feel free to mark the big tick over there and set this as the answer :)